# sql select statement with 3 tables?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have 3 related tables in the database, the table is A, B & C 
table structure as below

table A

```
id | name_A 
--- + --------- 
1 | Endru 
2 | maz 
3 | Hudson
```

table B

```
id | name_B 
----- + ------- 
10 | Food 
11 | clothes
```

table C

```
id | status 
--- + ------- 
1 | exist 
10 | exist 
3 | none
```

I want to produce like this

```
id | name_A | name_B | status 
------------------------------------------ 
1 | Endru | null | exist 
10 | null | food | exist 
3 | hudson | null | none
```

how do I achieve, I have tried using inner and left outer join but no success.

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think  the following query will fetch what you need

```
SELECT tableC.id, TableA.name_A,TableB.name_B,tableC.status
FROM tableC 
LEFT JOIN TableA on TableC.id = TableA .id
LEFT JOIN TableB on TableC.id = TableB .id
```

Comment: what if the id isn't in tableC, but is in table A or B?  the data wouldn't return

Comment: @MarshallTigerus According to sample, author does not need it(maz in table A)

Comment: I think that  he needs only the ids in tableC. He missed ids from tableB also at his example

Comment: sorry about the table, it's just an example .. but I've got the answer from @geoandri .thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using `union all` and aggregation:

```
select id, max(name_a) as name_a, max(name_b) as name_b,
       coalesce(max(status), 'none') as status
from (select id, name_a, NULL as name_b, NULL as status
      from tableA
      union all
      select id, NULL, name_b, NULL
      from tableB
      union all
      select id, NULL, NULL as name_b, status
      from tableC
     ) abc
group by id;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this query:

```
SELECT `id`, `name_A`, `name_B`, `status`
FROM `tableC`
LEFT JOIN  `tableA` USING (`id`)
LEFT JOIN  `tableB` USING (`id`)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use This Query :

```
SELECT tbc.Id,tba.Name_A,tbb.NameB,tbc.[Status] 
FROM tablec tbc 
INNER JOIN tablea tba on tba.Id = tbc.Id
INNER JOIN tableb tbb on tbb.Id = tbc.Id
```